# Conditional expectation of sum of numbers on 2 throws of a dice given their difference

Tags: probability

Let$  X$ and $Y$ be the numbers obtained on first and second throws of a fair die .
Calculate $E(X+Y|(X-Y)^2=1)$

I am doing basically $$E(X|(X-Y)^2=1)=E(Y|(X-Y)^2=1)$$
So $E(X+Y|(X-Y)^2=1)=2E(X|(X-Y)^2=1)$
$E(X+Y|(X-Y)^2=1)=2E(X|(X-Y)^2=1)$
implies $E(X|(X-Y)^2=1)=1/6(1+2+3+4+5+6)$

So I am getting it $7$ please help

Comment: "So I am getting it 7 " What does that mean?

Comment: the conditional expectation I am getting it as 7

Comment: Please edit your post to include your calculation.

Comment: The sum can only be odd given the difference is odd.

Comment: So while $7$ seems right to me, your working does not seem correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be seen by symmetry. Conditioning on $(X-Y)^2$ corresponds to the red stripes, and the distribution of the sum $X+Y$ (green stripes), which a priori ys symmetric around $X+Y=7$, is still symmetric around that value after the conditioning.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct.

To "see" the solution observe that throwing 2 fair dice the events that correspond to

$$(X-Y)^2=1$$

are 10

$$\{(1,2);(2,1);(2,3);(3,2);(3,4);(4,3);(4,5);(5,4);(5,6);(6,5)\}$$

given this sample space, the sum $X+Y$ is a rv taking values in

$$ Z=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $z=3$}  \\
\frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $z=5$}  \\
\frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $z=7$}  \\
\frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $z=9$}  \\
\frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $z=11$}
\end{cases}$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=7$$

Comment: thanks got it :)

Comment: @DebarghyaMukherjee : you're welcome! what about marking my answer as accepted?